# Why is Q1 taken as 'on' and Q2 as 'off' in the differential amplifier?

Tags: differential-amplifier

The book tells that we can arrive at the conclusion by *reasoning*. Why can the voltage at the emitter not be -0.7 V so that both the transistors would be on?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Because of the conditions on both bases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Why can the voltage at the emitter not be -0.7 V so that both the
> transistors would be on?*

If that happened then there would be 1.7 volts across the base-emitter junction of Q1 and, given that the base-emitter junction is a forward biased diode, having 1.7 volts across it (for even a fraction of a second) would destroy the transistor: -

[image]

Comment: So it's more like a practical limitation? But why does it not happen? What prevents the voltage from dropping to -0.7 V and damaging the p-n junction?

Comment: I modified the picture to show that to get that 1.7 volts you'll need "plenty of amps" flowing into the emitter current source and, that is just an impossibility in any sensible or meaningful circuit @DeviprasadVR

Comment: Oh and that's because of the exponential I v/s Vbe right? Thank you I understood it now!